# Best practise for polymorphic associations in MYSQL

Tags: sql, database, join, database-design, referential-integrity

I have a database with tables: **clients** *(client_id)* and **companies** *(company_id)*.

Both clients and companies can have **addresses** *(address_id)*, stored in the addresses table.

Is it better practice to:

1. Have 2 extra tables linking to companies and addresses:

   ```
   clients(client_id)
   client_addresses(client_id, address_id)
   companies(company_id)
   company_addresses(company_id, address_id)
   addresses (address_id)
   ```
2. Have a single table **entities** which has a primary key *entity_id* used to link all 3 tables:

   ```
   entities(entity_id)
   clients(client_id, entity_id)
   companies(company_id, entity_id)
   addresses (address_id, entity_id)
   ```

Comment: According to most ERP systems, they have only one table called something like GlobalAaddressBook that contains all addresses distinguished by the party id and table ref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another alternative.  Clients and Companies can be considered subclasses (or, if you prefer, subtypes) of a more generic entity, which might be called contacts.  A client is a contact and a company is a contact.  I'll skip over whether or not a contact can be both a client or a company.  If you choose to model things this way, you are faced with a problem due to the absence of inheritance (nevermind polymorphism) in the relational model.  There are several ways around this that various people have implemented with somewhat good results.
You can see these techniques outlined in three tags here in SO:

[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

The last technique is used in conjunction with the second one.

In addition to chasing down the info and the questions in each tag, you can do further research on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the only difference is in case you need some data specific to `client_addresses` or `company_addresses` to be stored - then the first approach will be better. Otherwise, you can use the second approach.

For example: if you wanna store number of employees a company has on certain address, then the first approach should be your choice. And if the relation of client or company to address is a simple key pair, you could use the second approach to work with fewer tables.

One more thing you have to figure out is if "entity" gives you any value. E.g. `client_addresses` stores clients on addresses (at least only keys) and what does `entities` store? If you want to get all addresses for a client with some ID, you'd have to join `client_addresses` and `addresses`; while with `entities`, you'd need to join 3 tables for the same thing.

If you ask me, I'd go with the first approach.

Comment: Uhh, I hope I didn't explain this in too complicated way... :)

Comment: Thanks Misa. I was thinking that the 'entities' table would only really supply a unique ID, and then addresses and clients could be joined directly using the entity_id. It would mean less tables, but I have th feeling I am missing soemhting